# Background-color and Background-image not working together

Tags: jquery, css

I am making a program and there are two different methods of setting the background: an `<input type=file>` and an `<input type=button>`. The button changes the background to black, and the file changes it to whatever file is chosen.

My problem is that when I try going back and forth, it gets stuck on one.

For example:

1. I click the button, changes to black
2. I click the file thing, changes to image
3. I click the button, stays image

Any ideas on why this happens?

CODE:

```
$('body').css('background-color','#000'); // for button
$('body').css('background-image','url(\''+imageSrc+'\')'); // for image (imageSrc is the image location)
```

Comment: Just so you know, the button uses ``background-color`` and the file thing uses ``background-image``

Comment: You need to provide us with some code in order to help you.

Comment: ok... I'll grab some and edit it in

Comment: you can try any slider like bx slider, cycle slider... for  image change and stay. and create button write jquery click function..

Answer (score 0, accepted):

CSS uses a `background-image` ahead of a `background-color`. If you want to click the button and show just the black background you would have to reset the `background-image` property as well like so:

```
$('body').css({
  backgroundImage: "",
  backgroundColor: "#000"
});
```

[DEMO](https://codepen.io/JTLR/pen/LWagrz)

Comment: I don't know if jQuery handles it for you, but you probably want to either set that to `null` or `"initial"` instead of just `""`.

Comment: that isn't how the jquery css function works., isn't doing anything